# Laravel 5.2 conditional validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I initially had fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email` as the fields in my sign up form. I need to add an option for signing up as a business.

My initial validation rules:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

I need to add a `business_name` field. I need the validation to be:

`first_name` and `last_name` are required xor `business_name` is required.

How can I do this in Laravel 5.2? I was looking at the `sometimes` rule - but I'm not sure if that is how this should be done.

edit:

I suppose it could almost be accomplished via:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'sometimes|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'sometimes|max:255',
        'business_name'=>'sometimes|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Although from my understanding of the `sometimes` rule, it will only validate if the key is present in the input array, therefore `first_name` could be present, and `last_name` could be non-existent which would would still validate as a "pass". This isn't the behavior that I'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might be looking for is the `required_without:foo,bar,...`

That validation rule says 'The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present'.

So you might have `business_name => required_without:first_name,last_name`

Comment: Perfect! I completely missed that in the documentation. Thanks for the answer. p.s. I'll upvote if I ever get the rep. Cheers, Chris

Comment: Great. Glad it helped.